# How do I remove a texture from a Color Sprite in the Scene Editor?

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode8, sktexture, sceneeditor

I want to remove the texture I chose in my colour sprite. But, not replace it with a different texture. Instead I want to just use a colour fill.

But I try to delete the texture in the attributes inspector and it just refills the box with the texture name after I click off. It won't remove the texture.

How can I just remove the texture in the scene editor and get a color sprite that is just a colour fill?

I just want a square box that has physics properties that I can either fill with a colour or make it colourless.

[image]

Comment: Just delete it and make a new node,  I do not think the people at apple thought about that

Comment: Really... So if I accidentally apply a texture there's basically no undo... How did someone not think to add that?

Comment: Under pressure, or just do not care, who knows lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a texture do the following for a workaround

Press Return while the texture name is highlighted in the attributes inspector box.  **This removes the texture.**